# Display is cut-off and stuck at 640x480; cannot detect monitor

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, display, resolution, monitor

I've recently installed **Ubuntu 11.10** on my PC and I have a resolution problem.

My screen resolution is set at 640x480 (4:3) and I can't see right the whole screen, the windows or the icons. The problem is that it does not have other options in monitor->display so I can choose the right one, and I think that it can't detect my monitor - it says "unknown"(i have a desktop with pentium4, at 3Ghz, asus motherboard and an Nvidia GeForce graphic card).

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480 default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm 640x480 50.0* 320x240 51.0
```

lspci -v | grep VGA

```
VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: PROLINK Microsystems Corp Device 1152 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 248, IRQ 16 Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M] [virtual] Expansion ROM at fe9e0000 [disabled] [size=128K] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: nvidia Kernel modules: nvidia_173, nouveau, nvidiaf
```

Comment: Try `xrandr -s 0` instead

Comment: @chrissi Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you tell us more about your [hardware setup](http://askubuntu.com/q/14008/18612) by editing this information back into your question or by posting a comment? Your issue sounds related to your graphics in particular, and this information can help us try to diagnose the cause of your issue. Thanks!

Comment: @UriHerrera thnx, i got it... it says: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        50.0* 
   320x240        51.0  
now what should i do??

Comment: I see you added that you have  an Nvidia card, again type this in the terminal so that you know which one is specifically: `lspci -v | grep VGA`

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: PROLINK Microsystems Corp Device 1152
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 248, IRQ 16
Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fe9e0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia_173, nouveau, nvidiaf

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

This is only part of the solution working for me! The way I fixed this one on my computer :

- Step 1

Must find someone (This is the other part of the solution !) with same monitor having a working configuration (Send SOS on forums !) ask him open terminal and use

```
xrandr --verbose
```

It will list the exact data you need to use for each resolution. Also at the beginning you will have the information for the monitor number - Mine was VGA1

- Step 2

You now should copy carefully the one you need in

> /etc/gdm/Init/Default

You must adjust the data according to the one found in step 1. Here the data are for my monitor as sample (You may have to sudo to edit it)

```
xrandr --newmode 1440x900 106.5MHz 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -HSync +VSync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900
```

copy these two lines just before the line

```
/sbin/initctl -q emit
```

- Step 3

log out then back now the resolution you add should be available in the monitor display preferences.

Good luck